Movie about ants that eat everything and grow to be huge
I watched this movie on TV in California roughly 20 years ago. I can't remember if it was in black and white, but it's possible.
The bits and pieces I remember were that a man (he might've been in his 20s?) had an ant farm of what appeared to be regular ants. I'm pretty sure he shortly fell into this ant farm and was eaten. I think I recall a shot of him covered in ants to the point of being unidentifiable. The ants got bigger and escaped, proceeding to eat just about anyone and anything all the while growing bigger without end.
The main characters were a man and a woman (that's all I've got about them, sorry. I was ~6 at the time, so I really only remember details about the ants). Near the end of the movie, I think these two people were hiding in a building as the ants were literally eating it apart. They were pretty big at this point. 
Then, I had to go to bed. I don't know what happens after that. I've spent the last 20 years expecting I may someday stumble into this movie again and I'll be able to finish it, but to no avail.
Can anyone here help me identify what movie this is?

Two films that come to mind is (1954) Them! (but I believe the ants were already full grown) and (1977) Empire of Ants, which is about how a Toxic spill makes the ants grow. I believe this one has a female lead, but she's a land develpor...

@DarthLocke Thank you! I've actually ruled out Them! before as, like you said, the ants start full grown. Empire of Ants seems possible though! The ants in that movie look a lot how I remember them. The plot doesn't seem familiar though, but I was pretty young and this was 20 years ago. I'll watch it and let you know!

Ya, I wasn't sure, I'll keep searching!

How big is "huge"?

@Paulie_D It's hard to be exact since it was really long ago, but at least the size of a car. Since I never finished it, I don't know how big the ants eventually got though, they may have kept growing. The ants that I've seen in images from googling "Empire of Ants" are pretty spot on, sizewise. That's looking like a good prospect.

Doesn't sound like a good fit for your description, but Phase IV http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0070531/ is another one for your "menacing ants SF film festival."
